# 'Series' object has no attribute 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can you help me fix this code? I'm trying to create a new dataframe with the lines I want.

```
import pandas as pd

#Creating dataframe
d = {'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'col2': ['azs','bdq','bzm','bqm','csm','dqs','cm','a','z','c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

x = df[df['col1'].int.contains("2|3|5",na=False)]
```

Comment: because int is not an attribute , `str.contains` not `int.contains`, but you are looking for `df[df['col1'].isin([2,3,5])]` i guess

Comment: Thats it! Thank you very much kinds stranger!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your final line, you want:

```
x = df[df['col1'].isin({2,3,5})]
```

You've modeled your membership test off of the `pd.Series.str.contains` method. The way to do a membership test for an int is to use the `pd.Series.isin` method, as shown above. Using a `set` (i.e. `{}`) is preferable for membership tests.